# Wordpress base category name change / permalink for only one category

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: Dashboard view]

I have a theme called MediPlus. There is a services section within the menu. Within the services I can create posts or categories. No matter what though, the base url / permalink is always https://example.com/services/post

I would like to change the permalink only for the services to something else. I tried several plugins and permalink settings, but couldn't manage to only change it for the services.

Any advice is very welcome.

Comment: How is the services custom post type being declared? Are you using a plugin to generate that custom post type, or is it part of your theme?

Comment: I think it came came with the theme.

Comment: I'm thinking about creating a new category in the "standard" post section with a certain name and move all posts i have in services to there if it otherwise gets too complicated.

Comment: Even though i would rather want to change the url. This is the theme by the way: https://themeforest.net/item/medi-plus-health-and-medical-wordpress-theme/17947326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's part of the theme, you'd have to create a template override. This should be done by creating a child theme.

If creating a child theme, and making the necessary modifications to the pre-established system isn't an option, then as you noted in your comment, you would have to look at moving them to a post category.

**UPDATE**

If going the route of implementing different permalink structures for individual categories (to avoid theme modifications), you could look at using a 3rd party plugin to accomplish this. I haven't tried any of these, myself, but from the looks of them, these ones should do the trick.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/

Comment: thanks. just had a quick check. is there a way to reflect the post category in the url? currently it's example.com/posttitle when i create a post

Comment: What is your desired format? Is it *base url*/*post category identifier*/*post title*/?

Comment: yeah. like that. if possible though only for certain categories and not for all

Comment: I just added a couple plugin options that may help accomplish this.

Comment: great. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ did the trick. just needed to regenerate every post url after installation. thanks a lot!